# How to find experience of an employee in ORACLE SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the work experience of employees in ORACLE SQL Developer.

I have the following columns in the table `employees`: `Hire_Date(DD-MM-YY)`, `First_name`, `Last_Name`, `Employee_id`, `Salary`, `Manager_ID` and so on.

I guess I need to apply some conversion but I'm not sure about the method or how to convert it.

---

I tried to subtract hire_date from Sysdate.

```sql
Select, Employee_id, First_name, Hire_Date, (Sysdate-Hire_Date) as year_Exp
from employees;
```

I am getting the output as

Actual result: 5966.52.333333333333333333333333333333333

Expected result: 5 Years or relevant years of experience

Comment: This is unexpected as date - date in oracle is a number.

Comment: We can do arithmetic with Oracle dates, using numbers as intervals. So 5966 is the number of days between those two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, It will help for you:

```
--Oracle 11g Express Edition
-- Put your Oracle SQL statement here and execute it

  select trunc(months_between(sysdate,hiredate)/12) year,
       trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,hiredate),12)) month,
       trunc(sysdate-add_months(hiredate,trunc(months_between(sysdate,hiredate)/12)*12+trunc(mod(months_between(sysdate,hiredate),12)))) day
from (Select to_date('15122000','DDMMYYYY') hiredate from dual);
```

Comment: This is MySQL syntax not the Oracle Syntax.

Comment: I have changed it in ORACLE.

Comment: Looks better now.